# How to handle client side Error handling in Kendo grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need some help. I want to get the server side error and show to kendo grid. How to do using client side JavaScript.Where i will find error in kendo grid.How to find it..If I am calling services that time some error is there in server like(Bad request or 500 )like that .How to get the this error in kendo grid.   It is possible to get the error in client side using javascript Kendo grid.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are loading data into Kendo grid using Ajax. Error event handling needs to be defined in the grid.

@DontVoteMeDown's answer works well with JavaScript. It's probably right answer to your question.

Razor implementation is more straight-forward and can be implemented as seen below.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoGridAjaxEditing.Models.ProductViewModel>()
      .Name("grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(product => product.ProductID).Width(100);
          columns.Bound(product => product.ProductName);
          columns.Bound(product => product.UnitsInStock).Width(250);
          columns.Command(commands =>
          {
              commands.Edit();
              commands.Destroy();
          }).Title("Commands").Width(200);
      })
      .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
      .DataSource(dataSource =>
          dataSource.Ajax()
            .Events(events => events.Error("grid_error")) // Handle the "error" event
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(product => product.ProductID);
                model.Field(product => product.ProductID).Editable(false);
            })
            .Create(create => create.Action("Products_Create", "Home"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("Products_Update", "Home"))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Products_Destroy", "Home"))
      )
      .Pageable()
)
<script>
function grid_error(e) {
    if (e.errors) {
        var message = "There are some errors:\n";
        // Create a message containing all errors.
        $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
            if ('errors' in value) {
                $.each(value.errors, function () {
                    message += this + "\n";
                });
            }
        });
        // Display the message
        alert(message);
        // Cancel the changes
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.cancelChanges();
    }
}
</script>
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-editing

Comment: How would you know that the error was thrown in the grid request and not on another ajax request?

Comment: Yes we are using pure JavaScript Kendo grid. Suppose I am passing wrong Url to server, that time I will show Error to User or Sometime Bad Request like that error I have to Handle in Kendo grid

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown it does http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-error

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-error

Just listen to the error event and adapt your server response to return a Json object when it throws an error.

In ASP.NET MVC projects, I use a method in my base controller that looks like this:

```
    protected JsonResult JsonError(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        if (modelState == null) new ArgumentNullException();
        if (modelState.IsValid) new ArgumentException();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        Response.StatusCode = 400;

        return Json(String.Join("\n", modelState.SelectMany(state => state.Value.Errors, (state, error) => error.ErrorMessage)));
    }
```

It will need some adapting for your odata service but this should get you started. The important part returning your error message with a 400 StatusCode (other codes may work).

Answer (score 0):

Writing this answer for anyone who might get stuck on this recently. There are basically three parts of this problem:-

1. What is your action method returning in case the code breaks on the server. This is what I returned for the Kendo ui to recognize that there was an error on the server:-

   `return Json(new { error = String.Format("Error message.") });`

Please note that if your JSON is not returned in the correct format from the server, kendo will not recognize that code broke.

2. How are you handling the error on the front end. If you are using `new kendo.data.DataSource` In that case you use the `error` property and assign that to a function like below:-

   ```
   var cloudStore = new kendo.data.DataSource({

   //other properties here

   //error property below
   error: function (e) {

       //since an error has occured, we are below removing the object we added to the grid
       $("#cloudGrid").each(function (item) {
           var grid = $(this).data("kendoGrid");
           if (e.sender === grid.dataSource) {
               grid.cancelChanges();
           }
       });

       //opening a popup to show the error message
       alert(e.errors);
       }
   )};
   ```
3. Kendo updates the grid on the frontend even before the object is actually updated on the backend, so in case an error occurs on the server, we have the update the grid accordingly. For that, notice my code above and see the `each` loop. That is where the grid is being reverted to its previous stage.